# Can anybody help me with the RPC url for ETC Testnets?

Tags: metamask, rpc

I am trying to setup a metamask with Custom RPC. My network is **Kotti**. What is the RPC URL for kotti that I put in metamask network setting?

Answer (score 0):

you can use chainlist (https://chainlist.org/) for that kind of stuff. It contains nearly all the EVM compatible chains out there :)

Comment: Following error occurred while I tried Adding kotti in the metamask using chainlist. Error

Expected an array with at least one valid string HTTPS url 'rpcUrls', Received: